# IoT Edge Test certificates expiration

Tags: azure-iot-edge

As far as I know IoT Edge will generate test (self signed) certificates (Device CA etc.) at startup if none were provided, right? Those are valid for 30 days.

What happens after those certificates expire? 
Is IoT Edge going to create new ones when it is restarted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When IoT Edge is restarted, the certificates are renewed.  However, this is not a production feasible approach imho. :)

You should have your own certificates installed on the device, but those certificats will offcourse expire as well on some day.  So, you'll need some kind of certificate rolling operation, but there doesn't seem to be any good documentation regarding this.  Therefore, I've created an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48467) on github for this